# How to use a struct from another file?

Tags: c, struct, header, extern

I am trying to use an *.h named structures in other files like clube.c which will create an array from the struct defined as Clubes.

structures.h:

```
extern typedef struct Clubes{
 char *codClube;
 char *nome;
 char *estadio;
};
```

no matter what I do it just doesn't appear in my clubes.c

Note: already did the include "structures.h"

Once again thanks in advance,
and if theres any info that I can give to help you help me just ask.

Comment: The `extern` keyword before the `typedef` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Just what i told before. Create the structure in a file and an array variable using that structure in another file.

Comment: Remove the `extern` keyword and include `structures.h`in your c. file. That's all.

Comment: @Rafael Botas: In C language the concept of linkage (controlled by such keywords as `static` or `extern`) is only applicable to *objects and functions.* In your code sample above you are declaring a type. Types by themselves have no linkage in C and cannot be declared with `extern` (or, more precisely, formally you can declare a type with `extern`, but it will simply make no sense). But specifying two storage class specifiers - `extern` and `typedef` - is illegal. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyword `typedef` just lets you define type, for example, `typedef int whole_number` this will create type `whole_number` and now you can use it as you would use `int`, `whole_number x = 5;` Same thing with structures. People use typedef on structures so they don't need to write `struct Clubes`:

```
typedef struct Clubes{
 char *codClube;
 char *nome;
 char *estadio;
} clubes;
```

And now you don't have to use `struct Clubes x;`, you can use `clubes x;` which is shorter and easier to write.

`Extern` keyword is giving you global linkage, and in this case it doesn't do anything.

Your question is a little bit confusing. If you want to create this structure, and then use it in other files you need to create header file:

```
#ifndef __CLUBES_H_
#define __CLUBES_H_ 1

struct Clubes{
 char *codClube;
 char *nome;
 char *estadio;
} clubes;

#endif
```

Save this in one header file, for example `clubes.h` and then in some other `c` code where you want to use this structure you just include header with `#include "clubes.h"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing what some of these keywords do.

struct creates a new type.  This doesn't create any instances of a type.

extern is for providing linkage for a global variable.

typedef is giving a new global name to an existing type.

```
/* clube.h */

/* define and declare the Clubes struct */
struct Clubes {
    char* codClube;
    char* nome;
    char* estadio;
}

/* typedef the Clubes struct.
 * Now you can say struct Clubes or Clubes_t in your code.
 */
typedef struct Clubes Clubes_t;

/* Now you've created global linkage for my_clubes.
 * I.e. two cpp files could both modify it
 */
extern struct Clubes my_clubes[2];



/* clube.c */

#include "clube.h"

/* Now you've got storage for my_clubes */
Clubes_t my_clubes[2];


/* some_other.c */

#include "clube.h"

void fun() {
    my_clubes[0].codClube = "foo";
    /* etc... */
}
```

Comment: That is what i am looking for. And i already got to that but the problem is that i want the array size to be the number of lines the file i will access has.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect use for header files

```
/* put this in clube.h */
struct Clubes{
 char *codClube;
 char *nome;
 char *estadio;
};

/* put this in clube.c */
#include "clube.h"

struct Clubes myarray[5];
```